# How to combine 2 lists using LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-4.0

Env.: .NET4 C#

Hi All,

I want to combine these 2 lists : `{ "A", "B", "C", "D" }` and `{ "1", "2", "3" }`

into this one:

```
{ "A1", "A2", "A3", "B1", "B2", "B3", "C1", "C2", "C3", "D1", "D2", "D3" }
```

Obviously, i could use nested loops. But I wonder if LINQ can help. 
As far as I understand, Zip() is not my friend in this case, right?

TIA,

Comment: Usually when starting something like this in LINQ, it's benificial to ask 'How would I do this if these were tables in a database'

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Essentially, you want to generate a cartesian product and then concatenate the elements of each 2-tuple. This is easiest to do in query-syntax:

```
var cartesianConcat = from a in seq1
                      from b in seq2
                      select a + b;
```

Comment: As Jon pointed out, * I * find this answer the most readable among the (as of this writing) 3. Actually, it matches the nested loop we'd use without LINQ, which others may take as an argument for NOT picking this answer. But of course, I'd love to be able to mark the 3 answers as accepted :-)

Answer (score 59):

Use SelectMany when you want to form the Cartesian product of two lists:

`aList.SelectMany(a => bList.Select(b => a + b))`

Comment: This is so elegant! This is why I love LINQ!

Comment: I like this, but wanted to combine two sets, rather like the SQL select t1,t2, so modifying slightly leads to

aList.SelectMany(a => bList.Select(b => new {a, b}))

Answer (score 26):

[`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx) is definitely the right approach, whether using multiple "from" clauses or with a direct call, but here's an alternative to Hightechrider's use of it:

```
var result = aList.SelectMany(a => bList, (a, b) => a + b);
```

I personally find this easier to understand as it's closer to the "multiple from" version: for each "a" in "aList", we produce a new sequence - in this case it's always "bList". For each (a, b) pair produced by the Cartesian join, we project to a result which is just the concatenation of the two.

Just to be clear: both approaches will work. I just prefer this one :)

As to whether this is clearer than the query expression syntax... I'm not sure. I *usually* use method calls when it's just a case of using a single operator, but for `Join`, `GroupJoin`, `SelectMany` and `GroupBy`, query expressions do simplify things. Try both and see which *you* find more readable :)

Comment: Hey Jon, always wanted to ask, how often are you on SO? :)

Comment: @The_Butcher: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/555/why-does-jon-skeet-never-sleep/566#566